# WCF service reports long running job progress in real time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, message-queue, msmq

I am developing a reliable WCF service that should make some long running work and has an ability to report such work progress. For passing tasks for processing service uses MSMQ binding, which provide reliability. For reporting progress, I think, it should utilize an another TCP/HTTP binding which more suitable for real time sending percentage to subscribed clients.

Is this way right? Any samples for doing that right?

**EDIT**

---

I found this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx), but it telling about an periodical client requests for percentage? My goal is server telling all subscribed clients about progress in real time.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main MS options:

- [WCF duplex contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)
  However, this will be limited to a local network only
- [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)
  will work over the internet, but is not based on WCF

Comment: Is the WCF duplex contracts requires client to make periodical requests to get the progress or server sends progress to client in real-time?

Comment: No, the client creates a listener on http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/. That's why the WCF duplex contracts are limited to LAN only.

Comment: SignalR negotiates the protocol & will use long polling if other technologies (like web sockets) aren't available.

Comment: I use SignalR before. But how do I setup build with SignalR?

Comment: @kseen SignalR has very good documentation on MSDN. I think you should ask a new question if you have specific problems with SignalR.

Answer (score 2):

Have you researched Pub/Sub pattern? Publisher (your service) can post updates and subscribers can listen to those updates.

Here is one [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx), [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34333/Topic-based-publish-subscribe-design-pattern-imp) to get you started...

Answer (score 0):

- [Reporting Server-Side Progress to Web Pages with SignalR](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/06/server-side-signalr/)
- [Progress bar for long running process with steps using asp.net, C#, SignalR](http://growingtech.blogspot.ru/2012/10/progress-bar-for-long-running-process.html)
- [Client Server Progress Bar using SignalR](http://westcountrydeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/client-server-progress-bar-using-signalr/)